# AS3: how to convert textfield into group of MovieClips?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textfield

I encountered that problem already a few times:

I have a dynamically created textfield, and I would like to convert this textfield into a movieclip containing a childmovieclip for each letter of the text, so that i can animate the letters individually (for example treat them as particles and make them explode). Of course the converted movieclip should still look the same way as the original textfield.

What's the quickest/easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by yourself, but implies lot of coding (basically, instead of filling the textfield, you should create singles movieclips containing a letter, either as textfield or bitmap, storing them in an array, and playing them later when needed).

OR

Simply use [TweenMax and SplitTextField](http://www.greensock.com/splittextfield/) :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to just create movieclips of each character in the string

To get an array of each character in the string, use `split`
    var myString:String="StackOverflow"; 
    var myArray:Array=myString.split(""); //['S', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k', 'O', 'v', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'l', 'o', 'w'];

And then I suppose you know the way

**OR**

If you have a static textfield (whose value doesn't change)

You could break it apart (Right Click>Break Apart), and that will give you textfields containing individual characters

Answer (score 0):

You can use the opensource lib called "TextAnim".

Check out:- http://code.google.com/p/textanim/